# Boto3 Authorization on IIS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, iis, boto3

I'm setting up a Django application on IIS with boto3. I got the application running however I'm unable to query any data from AWS due to no profile configuration being detected.

I tried running the application as a service account with AWS permissions. Giving the account R/W permissions to folder. 
Adding AWSProfileName and AWSProfilesLocation to web.config file 
I have double checked all common issues regarding this error, however, I think that my configuration might be wrong (perhaps in the web.config file)

Web.Config file:

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="Name_of_profile"/>
<add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="Path_to_credentials_folder"/>
```

The error I'm getting: The config profile (Profile_Name) could not be found

Comment: Do you have credentials stored in a local file, or are you using an IAM Role assigned to the Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using local file under user/.aws/ directory which includes my config and credentials files

Comment: @MrDarkness96 is IIS running as the specific user account that has the `.aws` folder? I'm thinking AWS credentials in environment variables would be more appropriate than using a `.aws` profile in this scenario.

Comment: @MarkB I have set both system variables and user variables pointing to .aws and to answer your question, yes, I am running as a specific account with access to that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured this out.

In my code I was using session to connect to AWS
`Session(Name_of_role)`.
The parameter should be empty:
`Session()`

In the web.config file:

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="aws-dev"/>
<add key="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" value=""/>
<add key="aws_secret_access_key" value=""/>
<add key="aws_session_token" value=""/>
<add key="AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" value="us-east-1" />
```

What happened?

Python is using environmental variables through [wfastcgi](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/) which means that it takes environmental variables from the web.config file under `<appSettings>` tag. The necessary configuration that I had to use was under [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).